# ON DELETE NO ACTION constraint in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

What I want to do is when I delete a row from the parent table to keep the data in the child table.

Meaning that if I have a table department, which is the parent table with two columns - `depNo` and `depName`, and a child table with three columns - `emNo`, `emName` and `depNo (FK)`.

I want to be able to delete the row in the parent table, but to keep the one in the child table (in my case it is connected with licenses and is a good idea to keep track of it, even if the user  is already deleted).

I guess `ON DELETE NO ACTION` won't work, because it will give me an error if I try to delete the row in the parent table.

`CASCADE` and `SET NULL` are not good in this case.

`SET Default` - it won't work because I can't make a default value - it could be different (and its 100% sure it will be).

Any ideas how to make it ?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the child data? Can you not move it to a historical table?

Comment: No, I need the data to stay in the child table - exactly like a historical table. So if I delete the row in the parent table, the FK in the child table should stay.

Comment: Then you need to remove the FK constraint from the child table and risk having inconsistent data. What you are suggesting is a bad database design. You should move child rows like that to a different table.

Comment: Okay, if that is the only way, then I will do it, its better than having inconsistent data. I guess this answers the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to keep child data with the foreign key column still containing the original value is to remove the foreign key constraint, risking the ability to add inconsistent data.

I suggest creating a new table without the foreign key constraint and copy the child rows to it before deletion.